# Preprocessing CT scans for kidney and tumor segmentation using UNet

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, normalization, image-segmentation

My ultimate goal is to train a network for kidney and tumor segmentation from a volumetric CT scan. I can’t figure out which approach is better for preprocessing.
In particular, after I made a clip of the Hounsfield units with the numpy.clip function, which of the two options I found should I choose?

- min max scaling + rescaling between 0 and 255
- subtract the mean value and divide by the standard deviation
  And if I choose the second method, do I have to scale between 0 and 255?

Comment: on what scaling was the network trained? the usual preprocessing is to scale values to some range around 1, not 255.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz actually I have to train the network, so I was wondering what are the advantages of one choice over the other.

Comment: @SilviaPolizzi "*after I made a clip of the Hounsfield units...*" did you check the range of your input data before clipping?

Comment: @Bilal Yes I have displayed the luminance histogram to choose an appropriate range